# same font is displaying differently in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

A

```css
p {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<p>
  this is a paragraph
</p>
```

simple font-family css style set, however it's showing different fonts in chrome and firefox, and I'm wondering why

Comment: Do you have screenshots of what it looks like for you? Because they look the exact same to me on both browsers

Comment: `monospace` isn’t a specific font. It just means “make all characters the same width.” The browser can use whatever font it wants to show it, so naturally the end result may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser (or the system) decides which font it will use for the font-family you give it.

I see a slight difference in Safari (on the right) but they are the same on my Chrome and Firefox on ***OSX***:

[image]

Right-click on the element and choose inspect. Go to "Computed"

- In Chrome when I scroll down I see "Rendered Fonts: Menlo - Local file"
- In Firefox and Safari I need to go to Fonts on the right and in FX I see "Menlo Regular"
- In Safari I see it is using "Courier"

Menlo is the native OSX monospaced font used in native applications like terminal. Why Safari has chosen to not use the same font is interesting.